# Php Mail Attachment error

Tags: php, email, attachment

What's wrong in my code? Mail sending fine and text also fine but the attachment showing like `noname.txt` Please help.

```
$upload_name=$_FILES["resume"]["name"];
$upload_type=$_FILES["resume"]["type"];
$upload_size=$_FILES["resume"]["size"];
$upload_temp=$_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"];

$file = $upload_temp;
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
$num = md5(uniqid(time()));
$email_to = "noname@example.com";
$email_subject = $name . " Applied for a job in website careers page";
$email_message = "<b>Form details below.</b><br />";
$email_message .= "<tr><td><strong>Last Name</strong> </td><td>".$name."     </td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone</strong> </td><td>".$phone." </td></tr>";
$headers .='Reply-To: '. $email_to . "\r\n" ;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;  boundary=\"".$num."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $email_message."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type:".$upload_type.";  name=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
 $headers .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
 $headers .= "--".$num."--"; 

 if(@mail($email_to, $email_subject, "", $headers)){
        echo "Mail Send";
 }
else  {
       echo "Mail not sent.";
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you move the `Content-Disposition` header to before the `$headers .= $email_message."\r\n\r\n";` line does the problem go away?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I have add  example code for attach file to send in mail

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```

If you send zip file try to use following

```
<?php    $my_file = "filename.zip";
    $my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/";
    $my_name = "resr";
    $my_mail = "test@resr.com";
    $my_replyto = "test@test.com";
    $my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
    $my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
    mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
?>
```

Comment: what's the difference between your code and my code?